# When using jQuery .append, child's parent does not get update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery `.append()` to move a `<li>` from one `<ul>` to another. But when it's moved, it keeps the same parent class, when I want it to have the new `<ul>`'s parent class.

Ex. When I move it from `.players` class to `.confirm`, it still has the parent classes of `.players` instead of `.confirm`.

Any idea how I can update the parent of the moved `<li>`? Or am I just doing something wrong?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="listOptions confirm">
   <li><a href="" class="select">Item 1 that was taken from .players</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="listOptions players">
   <li id="player-li-1000"><a href="" class="select">Item 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.listOptions.confirm').append($('#player-li-' + playerID));
```

Comment: Could you show me HTML?

Comment: What is a parent class? i would assume that's the class of the parent element, which is not related to the li and therefore should not move with it when you move it.

Comment: Post the js you used moving it and html

Comment: Could you please [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) your work? Your question as is doesn't make much since, and the code you show doesn't really reveal the "problem" you might be having.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Essentially I want any link clicked in ".listOptions.confirm" to not be active. But even when I remove the "select" class, they're still clickable, as if the class was still there.

Answer (score 1):

Child DOM elements do not automatically acquire the classes of their parent.

```
var listA = $('<ul></ul>').addClass('parentA').appendTo(document.body);
var item = $('<li></li>').appendTo(listA);

console.log(item.hasClass('parentA')); // returns false
```

So while the **li** element may [*inherit* some CSS style properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance) from its parent, the child and parent elements do not share the same class!

You'd have to do it yourself if you want to muck around with an element's CSS classes.

```
// Set up list A and list item
var listA = $('<ul></ul>').addClass('parentA').appendTo(document.body);
var item = $('<li></li>').addClass('parentA').appendTo(listA);
console.log(item.hasClass('parentA')); // returns true

// Set up list B and move list item to list B
var listB = $('<ul></ul>').addClass('parentB').appendTo(document.body);
listB.append(item);
console.log(item.hasClass('parentA')); // returns true
console.log(item.hasClass('parentB')); // returns false
// Note classes did not change even though the child item now belongs to a different parent

// Change classes
item.removeClass('parentA').addClass('parentB');
console.log(item.hasClass('parentA')); // returns false
console.log(item.hasClass('parentB')); // returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using .clone(false) for this, instead of append(). It seems to do the trick for what I want. Thanks for all the suggestions.

**Edit:** Sorry, I used .clone(false).appendTo to get the results I was after.

Answer (score 0):

try adding .eq(0).clone() to the end of the jquery element you are trying to copy over. this will make a copy of the li you are trying to move into the ul. thats assuming that you have playerId set to something and this is being called after the element is added to the page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var playerID = 1000;
    $('.listOptions.confirm').append($('#player-li-' + playerID).eq(0).clone());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're trying to do.  The actual classes that an element has are not affected by the classes of parent elements.  If you really want to change its class when you move it in the dom, you need to add that class directly in your javascript code, e.g. with jQuery's `addClass()`.

More likely, though, if you're just trying to style it or otherwise make it identifiable via selector, then that should work without changing anything, e.g. `$(.confirm li)`, or in css:

```
.confirm li {. . .}
```

If you mean that you actually want to change the class of the parent element (e.g. the `<ul>`), then you can do that by using a combination of `removeClass()` and `addClass()` on that parent element (obtainable by `parent()`, if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

It's so unclear what you want to achieve but I did this for you

> [`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/pzf6H/)

Hope this is what you trying to do.

Comment: Ya, I'm sorry I've been so bad at explaining it. I'll trying doing a jsfiddle.

Comment: Is this what you want to do? Have you checked the jsFiddle?